# Is there a practical way to verify if a function is locally injective?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

For example, it was asked to me whether 
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}{
u=xy\\
v=x^2+y^2
}\end{array}\right.$$
is locally injective at $(1,1)$.

I don't need the answer to this specific question, I just need to know how to deal with this kind of problem in general.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem

Comment: @DanRust, but in this case teh Inverse Function Therem doesn't apply, right? As $\det(f'(1,1))=0$.

Comment: This particular function is not injective since $f(1+h,1) = f(1,1+h)$.

Comment: Is there any way to do this looking at the derivatives?

Comment: Once the inverse function theorem doesn't work, it is a matter of trial and error.  Try to find symetry in the definition.